# Karate UI executed from a spring boot application

Tags: karate

I am running Karate UI tests that are kicked off from a spring boot application, which works fine. However, if the driver fails, karate appears to be killing the whole process. I saw that System.exit() is used in different places in the Karate API. Is there a strategy for avoiding Karate getting killed of with System.exit()? Must I create custom code that doesn't include System.exit()? Any suggestions?
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree that System.exit() is not-ideal, I remember that it made sense in the "fat jar" - so is that what you are using?

The best thing you could do is submit a PR or at least suggest which part of the code comes into play for your case. Karate certainly has not been designed to be kicked off from a web-app, so yes - this may need some investigation.

Comment: Yes, the files are all in one jar and my spring boot app organizes, schedule, and executes a plethora of karate ui features. I think throwing a RuntimeException would be better. We would be able to recover from that. I haven't scene how this behaves when executed from a JUnit runner though, I think throwing a RuntimeException would yield a failure just as well as System.exit in that use case

Comment: @ChrisOpacki just to be clear, this is a non-typical use-case and we will depend on community contributions for this to be fixed